# What is the preferred behavior of form validation?

Tags: forms, gui-design, validation

What is really the preferred behavior of form validation? When should the validation take place?

- When the user clicks "save"
- When the input field is out of focus
- As the user types

Is the preferred way the same on long vs. short forms, wizards and so on?
What do you think?

(The form will be on desktop platform only)

Comment: See this article https://alistapart.com/article/inline-validation-in-web-forms for information about validating as the user enters information. The article documents actual user testing.

Comment: ^ The ALAP article is an oldie, but it has some great insight into how to test and good principals for doing it right even 8 years later.

Comment: In addition, on multi-page forms, the user should be allowed to go on to the next page even if there are empty required fields on the current page. That way, the user can proceed and work on the rest of the form, then come back and fill out the other stuff later. Otherwise, I'll just put in dummy information, then maybe forget to replace it with real information before submitting.

Answer (score 39):

Generally,

> The way in which validation should be implemented varies based on the
>   unique needs of the form.  However, in general, if the user’s input is
>   incorrect, the system should inform the user by providing an
>   identifiable and clear message that aids in correcting the error.

from https://www.nngroup.com/articles/indicators-validations-notifications/

More to the point,

> The right time to inform about the success/failure of provided data is
>   right after the user has submitted the information. Inline
>   form validation that immediately informs users about the correctness
>   of provided data results in an increase in the conversion rate.

from https://designmodo.com/ux-form-validation/

Working a lot with forms, I believe the least annoying way is to do it when **the input field is out of focus until the user fixes the error**.

- When the user clicks "save" => It is a bit too late for validation
- When the input field is out of focus => **It is just the right time**
- As the user types => It is a bit too early for validation

Twitter has it quite right

[image: twitter]

Comment: In addition to this answer: do not forget to validate both the client side and server side. There is always some user with javascript disabled or some weird browser addon that would allow him to pass client side validation.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth In that case, would it be correct to say to do Client-Side validation after focus is lost and server-side once the save button is pressed?

Comment: @SGR Yes, it is.

Comment: @SGR sometimes server side validation can be done, for example when you lose focus on a username field, you may want to trigger a server side call to verify it's unique.

Comment: I like validation on losing focus, but only if user actually entered anything. I find it annoying when I switch away from empty form and suddenly every field is marked as "invalid".

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth: Or developer tools. Or Firebug. Or curl. Or netcat. Or...

Comment: @Matthew - Although I agree that approach is ideal, I've found it to cause many bugs with coworkers who don't hook each asynchronous call into the form submission.  This results in behavior like: "user enters zip code -> asynchronous validation call is made -> user clicks submit and moves to the next page because the zip code validation isn't finished".  Hooking each async call into the submit isn't something I've seen frameworks tackle, so if you're on a team with less confident developers - I just wouldn't bother.

Comment: @Matthew: That's not server side validation. It may call the server but is still client side validation. Server side validation **does not need to inform the user that data is invalid** although that is a nice thing to do. The primary role of server side validation is preventing incorrect data from being saved in the database. This is different from client side validation whose primary role is to inform user that the entered data is incorrect. I've seen plenty of corrupt databases because developers neglect proper sever side validation.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth: definitely, but the even more important reason is that sooner or later there will be a curious and/or malign client doing POST to your server without ever having invoked the web page with the validation scripts. If these POSTs are not faulted in the  server, your database will be polluted with junk ... or much, much worse. More DB Admin experience than User Experience, I agree.

Comment: @slebetman That's correct, I'm dumb.

Comment: I'd argue an exception to this guideline for the password field strength indicator when setting a new password. It's extremely preferable for those indicators to update in real time as each character is typed.

Comment: One thing to consider when there are multiple fields with required inputs is what happens when going back from one field to fix a previous error. It can make a new error appear. So you may want to avoid showing error in these cases

Answer (score 4):

Validation should be done per input field:

- **when the user has finished entering his answer**: when the field is focused out or after a specific timeout that you consider the user finished typing (as suggested [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/14697/32130))
- while on focus, the entered information does not validate **and extra characters won't make the validation proceed**: for example, the user enters an invalid character that won't make the field pass validation

Answer (score 4):

Edit:

For critical forms such as **Login, Online transactions, providing any type of information** it is necessary to use server validations over https that will execute when users hit the Submit button.

For **field level validations such as email, tel, number** we can take advantage of client-side validations but with fallback for browsers that have disabled JavaScript;

---

## [Native client-side validations](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/) take place when the condition is met / as the user types.

Looking at the new values in **type attribute** `<input type="email" />`,

and the best implemented in almost all browsers **Pattern attribute** `<input type="tel" pattern="^\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{4}$" >`

We are experiencing form validations as the user types / conditions are met [ [**HTML5 client-side form validations**](https://www.sitepoint.com/client-side-form-validation-html5/) ]. The program/code doesn't send a request to server to validate the information, **browsers are taking care of it**.

**Examples:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should note that - for web contexts - using client-side validation is not sufficient from a security point of view. All content should be validated on the server side as well to make sure its not possible to forge requests (circumventing browser-side validation is trivial). This is sometimes overlooked when using client-side validation and can lead to major security flaws and data inconsistency. Especially the bolded part of your answer could be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 3):

The user should be informed about an error **as early as possible**, in all types of forms (wizards, long forms, etc).

If it is possible to give error feedback while the user types, then do it. This will allow the user to **fix his error more efficiently**, because the cursor and his mind is located on the subject of the error.

I must stress the difference between informing the user about an error and **stopping the user**. The user may be informed about an error while he types, but he will not be stopped until the form is submitted or the field is out of focus. When to stop the user, depends from the severity of the error, the use case of the form, the type of the form and many other factors.

First of all though, you should try to **prevent errors** , i.e. by using list boxes.

Comment: Wondering if it is a personal preference that I don't want to be given an error when still typing my data.

Comment: @DimitraMiha, I agree that I do not like syntax and grammar errors in a word processor while I type, because they break your flow of thoughts, but free text writting in a word processor and form filling are completely different use cases. So imagine you have a "user name" validation that you must not use capitals. It will be annoying for the user to find this after he types the user name and leaves the field.

Comment: I'm with you, @DimitraMiha. I hate getting a  "Bad Email Address" error while I'm still typing it. "Hold your horses! I haven't gotten to the @ yet!"

Comment: It seems to me that as a general rule, getting an error midway through would be helpful if the page can determine that what the user's typed so far cannot possibly lead to a result it can accept. So in @DesignerAnalyst's example, you should get an error straight away, since nothing else you type (other than backspace) will result in a valid username, but for an email address, you shouldn't get an alert for a missing @ until focus leaves the box.

Comment: @rand337 That pretty much sums up my take on it perfectly. "Incompleteness" should be assessed only after the user has _completed_ their input. "Incorrectness" should be assessed immediately.

Comment: For validations like "user name can't contain capitals" I also prefer validation as you type, but rather than giving an "error" when you type a capital I prevent invalid characters from being entered in the field at all, and a "tip" comes up if you _attempt_ to type one. This way the data in the fields is _never_ invalid.  That said, you _still_ have to validate everything before saving it, because it could be tampered with in between the form and the server.

Comment: @StephenP better yet, for capitalization requirements specifically, *do* allow the incorrectly cased letters to be typed, but convert them to the required case in real-time.

Comment: @DanHenderson true, what you say is better. I just used this as an example to prove my point.

Answer (score 2):

## Provide feedback while you still have their focus

This is a delicate balance, as the answers here indicate. Informing the user after they've completed the whole form (as some apps/sites still do) interrupts the flow.

#### Avoid breaking their concentration

You'll create less frustration and reduce cognitive load if you follow a "just-in-time" principal of informing progressively throughout the form. This is usually referred to as *in-line validation*.

You want to inform them:

- While the field is still in focus
- After they *think* they have something meaningful entered
- Before focus is shifted the next thing

#### Guess and test

The catch with just-in-time information is that you can't be *entirely* certain when the user is done typing/thinking.

Too early and you break their concentration on the field in question.
Too late and they're already onto the next one. Focus broken again.

Make an educated guess about the `focus + typing + pause` delay and then test it in action. Test with a prototype and continue watching your metrics (form abandonment, entry error) in production. Fine tune when you reach the happy middle ground.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch. At first, I was convinced of one option. But thinking more carefully the answer, in my opinion, is **Depends, and all 3**.

### 1. Depends on the input field

#### a. As user types

There are different types of inputs, and some inputs need different validation.

- A password could be validated as the user types. If your site does not accept for example simple passwords like "123" that could be validated on the fly. You see this in "password straight" evaluators.
- Choosing a username could be also validated on the fly as user types.
- Typing a phone number with non-numeric characters, like letters, slashes or spaces could display a warning when detecting one.

#### b. When user leaves the field

This should mark some possible typing errors, for example, a not valid email, a name with only one letter or an invalid postal code.

#### c. Send or Next Step

Here is a bit obvious that a "Send or Next step" button should mark the empty required fields.

---

### 2. Aditional help

Some fields could have additional help like autocomplete when typing common things like places, county, probably States.

---

### 3. Validation warnings of different intensity

What I want to explore here is that some validations can be for example more subtle, for example, when typing an email the field could be a light gray color as the background, and when the email is valid (after having an @ and a final .something) change to white.

But when validating empty fields this same field can turn to a strong angry red.

---

### 4. Choose the right color scheme from start

I need to use a cell phone provider's page constantly to add some cash to my phone.

But the "modern cool sleek" color scheme they have makes a check box for an "I accept terms and conditions" almost totally invisible. I assure you, that I would mark it if I could see it from start.